# How can I create auto open qrcode links

Tags: php, qr-code

I'm already using php qrcode class here is my code

```
$qrcodeData = urlencode(get_bloginfo('home').'?q=userControl&gameID=4765&userID=1234');

qr_img.php?d='.$qrcodeData.';
```

I want to like this, after scan qrcode auto open web page;
is it possible?

Comment: depends upon QR code scanner.if internet is enabled in your phone having qr code scanner app,you can track hits. http://yourls.org/ provides this facility.put the short url in your QR code and you can track hits,devices,os etc.

Answer (score 2):

A QR code just contains a string.  It is up to the QR reader to interpret it.  Some scanners will automatically open URLs - but you can't force them to do so.